# Changing StackPanel Background color with ColorAnimation

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, stackpanel, coloranimation

Well, I'm trying to change the Background color of a StackPanel in a DataTemplate using ColorAnimation:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type logic:Sensor}">
        <StackPanel Name="SensorPanel" MouseDown="SensorPanel_MouseDown">
        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="0">
                <!--<Setter TargetName="SensorPanel" Property="Background" Value="LawnGreen" />-->

                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="SensorPanel" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="LawnGreen" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="4">
                            </ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

No Compile-Time Errors. But when I run this an InvalidOperationException is thrown: "'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'."

What? :D

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399210/background-property-does-not-point-to-a-dependencyobject-in-path-0-1)
You may see this link as it similar to your problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code worked perfectly for me.  I just made minor modifications.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Sensor}">
        <StackPanel Name="SensorPanel" Background="LightBlue" Width="100" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <ToggleButton Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="Set status=0" />
        </StackPanel>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="0">
                <!--<Setter TargetName="SensorPanel" Property="Background" Value="LawnGreen" />-->

                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="SensorPanel" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            To="LawnGreen" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="4">
                            </ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sensors}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, But is it Supposed to repeat forever? because it does. :(

Comment: RepeatBehaviour="4x" will fix it.  Specifying a number is interpreted as a TimeSpan so what you've got means '04:00:00' or 'for 4 hours'.

Answer (score 12):

For documentation purposes:

It is a little hard to use `(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`. The real problem is that `ColorAnimation` only works for the `Color` property, instead of `Brush`. For me this is the trick:

Define your panel brush...

```
<StackPanel Name="SensorPanel" MouseDown="SensorPanel_MouseDown">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" x:Name="PanelColor"/>
    </StackPanel.Background>
</StackPanel>
```

...then animate the `Color` property of `SolidColorBrush` instead:

```
<ColorAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="PanelColor" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
    To="LawnGreen" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="4">
```